# Having issue with hard hat tests not minting or getting signers

Tags: erc-721, testing, hardhat

I am having trouble with the hardhat tests not working as expected.

I have the following simple contract:

```
pragma solidity 0.8.11;
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Enumerable.sol";

// import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol"

contract EventTicket is ERC721, ERC721URIStorage, ERC721Enumerable, Ownable {
    using Counters for Counters.Counter;
    Counters.Counter private _tokenIds;

    uint256 maxSupply;
    uint256 maxAllowedPerTransaction;
    string baseURI;

    constructor(
        string memory assetBaseURI
    ) ERC721("ESPER Ticket", "ESTK") {
        baseURI = assetBaseURI;
    }

    function mintNFT(address recipient, uint256 count)
        public
        returns (uint256)
    {
        // require(totalSupply() + count < maxSupply);
        // require(count <= maxAllowedPerTransaction);

        _tokenIds.increment();

        uint256 newItemId = _tokenIds.current();
        _mint(recipient, newItemId);
        _setTokenURI(newItemId, tokenURI(newItemId));
        return newItemId;
    }

    function _baseURI() internal view override(ERC721) returns (string memory) {
        return baseURI;
    }

    function _beforeTokenTransfer(
        address from,
        address to,
        uint256 tokenId
    ) internal override(ERC721, ERC721Enumerable) {
        super._beforeTokenTransfer(from, to, tokenId);
    }

    function _burn(uint256 tokenId)
        internal
        override(ERC721, ERC721URIStorage)
    {
        super._burn(tokenId);
    }

    function tokenURI(uint256 tokenId)
        public
        view
        override(ERC721, ERC721URIStorage)
        returns (string memory)
    {
        return super.tokenURI(tokenId);
    }

    function supportsInterface(bytes4 interfaceId)
        public
        view
        override(ERC721, ERC721Enumerable)
        returns (bool)
    {
        return supportsInterface(interfaceId);
    }
}
```

I have the following test:

```
it("NFT is minted", async function () {
    const Contract = await ethers.getContractFactory("EventTicket");
    contract = await Contract.deploy("https://token.com/foo")

    const [account1] = await ethers.getSigners();
    expect(await contract.balanceOf(account1.address)).to.equal(0);
    const tx = await contract.connect(account1).mintNFT(account1.address, 1);
    console.log(await contract.balanceOf(account1.address));
    expect(await contract.balanceOf(account1.address)).to.equal(1);
  });
```

There are a 2 things I am noticing. The balance never sets to 1. The getSigner() never returns more than one account.. Is there some extra configuration I need to do to test locally?

Answer (score 0):

`npx hardhat test --network hardhat` is how I had to get my tests to run.